# How to make udhcpc changes permanent in Poky (Yokto) Dizzy distribution

Tags: linux, networking, yocto

I used the following command:

```
udhcpc -i eth0
```

and configured the `eth0` device to DHCP. 
Now, running `ifconfig` shows me my dynamic IP address.

After I reboot the device, this configuration was gone;
i.e., running `ifconfig` shows me only `lo`.

I created a file `/etc/network/interfaces` placing this:

```
 # /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
 auto lo                                                           
 iface lo inet loopback                                            

 auto eth0                                                         
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But that didn't work.

1. How can I set this up?
2. How can I get documentation when using a new distribution?  I am used to Debian and this is very different. I'd like to be able to figure things out instead of asking the community. :)
3. Also, on a different note, Debian has `apt-get`.  What's the equivalent package manager for Poky? I couldn't find anything of this sort.

Answer (score 2):

1. Well, `/etc/network/interfaces` should work for you, at least if you have the `init-ifupdowm` package installed. Are you using sysv init or systemd? What machine are you using? Are you using `Poky` or some other distribution?
   Which release of the build system and distribution are you using? See for example how meta-ti handles it for the beagleboard [beagleboard interfaces file](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ti/tree/recipes-core/init-ifupdown/init-ifupdown-1.0/beagleboard/interfaces)
2. If you're looking for documentation on the Yocto Project, look at [Yocto Project Documentation](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ti/tree/recipes-core/init-ifupdown/init-ifupdown-1.0/beagleboard/interfaces). The documentation for the Yocto Project is excellent and comprehensive.
3. Well, it depends on which package format you're using. (rpm, deb, or ipk). For rpm it's normally smart (ontop of rpm), for ipk it's opkg, and for deb you have the apt (ontop of dpkg).